# Define google analytics conversion as a custom event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have a website that is using an iframe to host a full stack application to handle the custom form on the site. I need the form submission, to be counted as a conversion event and connected to google ads.

Tech stack used is React & Express.

Best I've understood so far is that I need to somehow link the parent site to the iframe, and then have the app send an event to GA.

However, even when trying to simply send an event, I'm not ever seeing that occur within GA. I created a custom event on the platform and am trying to call it via the code below, on my front end.

```
import ReactGA from 'react-ga4';

function App() {
  ReactGA.initialize('G-ID', { debug: true });
  ReactGA.event({
    category: "Application",
    action: "Submitted",
    label: "label", // optional
    value: 1, // optional
  });
  ReactGA.gtag('config', 'your GA measurement id', {
    'linker': {
      'domains': ['domain-to-link']
    }
  });
```

I'm new to GA, but have done several hours of research before posting and have found very little specific information relating to this. Also, yes those placeholders texts such as G-ID and domain-to-link have been customized, just changed for this post per security.

I spend several hours researching information and attempting to apply it. This includes trying various libraries and differing code placements such as back end routes vs front end. My expectation meaning a passing 'test' would be to have the code create an update within GA showing the event took place.

Answer (score 0):

Look, the category, action, label parameters were related to `Universal Analytics` which are now deprecated. However, if you need these you can create them as `Custom Dimensions` for your `Custom Event`.
if you are using only google analytics then you should copy the js installation code from your analytics account and pass it to the developer team to put them on the  tag of the website.
this code is found as I explain below (but, I recommend using `GTM` instead of `GTAG`).
1- log into your analytics.account
2- go to admin or administration
3- then go to the `Data Stream` section
[image]

4- select your stream and then click on `configure tag settings`
[image]

5- then click on installation manual or something similar (mine is in Italian  and sometimes translate does not work).
6- copy the `GTAG` code and give it to the developers:
[image]

This way you have just installed google analytics tool on your website. BUT, it is not finished. you should create your custom dimensions which can be done from the yellow highlighted part in the first photo.

for more info that how you can send the info from your website to GA, you can follow [Analytics Mania - Google Analytics & Tag Manager](https://www.youtube.com/@AnalyticsMania)